# How to run node.js application from script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run my node.js application from a script I have written:

```
    echo "Starting node application"
    sudo node /home/pi/PPBot/bot.js

    exit 0
```

I run the script like this: `sudo /etc/init.d/botscript`

The output when running the script is:

```
    Start node application
    sudo: node: command not found
```

I have also tried replacing `node` by `/home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v.8.11.3/bin/node`  but this resulted in the same output.

I have already installed NodeJS through NVM. Simply using the command `node bot.js` works from the command line. However as can be seen above it does not work through the script.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run a simple node js file then use the command
-> node filename 
ex.: node server.js

if you want to run a node js file with nodemon then use the command
-> nodemon filename 
 ex.: nodemon server.js

Comment: The OP is obviously already familiar with how to run node in general, the question was about a specific issue with running node from a command script and nodemon wasn't even mentioned at all. This answer isn't really helpful.